# Import function from addon's /lib into unit test?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an addon that defines a function in `my-addon/lib/my-function.js`. This function is used by another addon at build time via `var myFunction = require("my-addon/lib/my-function")` from the consuming addon's `index.js`.

This works great for the consuming addon, but I can’t figure out how to import the function into unit tests. Using `require` results in:

`` Error: Could not find module `my-addon/lib/my-function` imported from `(require)` ``

It looks like addon tests limit the modules available for import to the dummy app. Anyone know a way to include my function as a module in the dummy app, or a way to directly import the module from tests?

Comment: Learned a lot about Ember.js since writing this. I believe the issue is that the resolver only looks in a certain set of predetermined locations. One would need to alter the resolver to fix this issue. I'll see about coming up with an answer eventually.